# How is this SQL function getting the first day of the previous month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function that gets the first day of the previous month but I would like to understand "DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()) - 2" part how is it contributing in getting the first day of the previous month. The full function is given as code.

I know what dateadd and datediff functions do but I am not sure what the -1 (in the datediff function) and -2 in the dateadd function are doing.

```
SELECT @prev_month_first_date = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()) - 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewriting it like this:

```
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '20100101', getdate()) - 1, '20100101')
```

probably makes it clearer.

There's some dodgy and obscure stuff going on.

This

```
DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate())
```

counts the month boundaries crossed between two dates, the first one is

```
   cast(-1 as datetime) --1899-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Then it subtracts 2 from that and add that many months to

```
 cast(0 as datetime) --1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: sorry just to check, where does '20100101' come from?

Comment: It's an arbitrary anchor date.  I usually pick a day that's far enough in the past to not worry about negative numbers (though they would work fine here), but close enough that a datediff using seconds won't overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The -1 represents the number of days from the "zero date" (1900-01-01):

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, -1);

-- 1899-12-31 0:00
```

It's a cryptic way to just grab a starting date to perform datediffs against, for example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate());
-- or
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, '18991231', getdate());

-- Both yield:
1431
```

So the expression becomes:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, (1431 - 2), 0);
```

Which is "add 1429 months to zero date (1900-01-01)":

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, (1431 - 2), '19000101');
```

Which yields:

```
2019-02-01 0:00
```

Again `0` and `-1` are just magic numbers here to represent two goalpost dates to be used in cryptic and "clever" calculations.

Personally I find such clever magic confusing and unhelpful. The beginning of the previous month can also be represented by the following expression, which is actually fewer characters *and* easier to follow in English (subtract two months from today (Jan 25), move to the end of that month (Jan 31), then add a day (Feb 1)):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-2,GETDATE())));
```

Just demonstrating there are many ways to skin this cat. Gordon's `DATEFROMPARTS` is equally valid, and I actually can't stand the `EOMONTH()` function, but this form allows you to only specify `GETDATE()` once.

Comment: Thank you for your response Aaron. Just to check, in simple terms you are going two months back and then adding one day which will result in the first day of the previous month. Just would like you to confirm my understanding?

Comment: @Ali_M Yes, that's right, go back to the last day from two months ago, then the next day is the first day from a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use something like this:

```
select dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate(), month(getdate(), 1))
```

The intention of this is much clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer OP's question.